# React-native useState updating even thought it has not been called

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

So I'm doing something fairly simple in with react-native. I have a function that creates a copy of the state which is initially an array, I then update the copy and then I would eventually call my setState in order to update the original array. However, when I mutate the copy, for some odd reason it also mutates the array from the state even if I don't call setState. I tried everything that I thought might fix it, using slice, [...copy], splicing it, nothing, it still mutates, and why, I just don't understand why it mutates? If anyone can help me that would be really appreciated.

Here is the function

```js
function completeTaskHandler(goalName, taskId, taskIndex, updateAction) {
        const taskSnapShot = tasks.slice();
        console.log(taskSnapShot);//logs the copy
        console.log(tasks);// logs the original array
        taskSnapShot[taskIndex].isComplete = "true";
        console.log(taskSnapShot);//results in mutated array
        console.log(tasks);//Also results in mutated array why??
    };
```

Here is the full Code block

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

//Custom Components
import Task from "../../components/local/goals/EditGoalTask";

//Header Custom Component
import CustomBackButton from "../../components/HeaderButtonDark";

//Controllers
import { DefaultText, SmallText, HeaderText, SmallTextItalic } from "../../controllers/TextController";

//Constants
import Colors from "../../constants/Colors";

//Redux reducers
import { udpateTask } from "../../store/actions/user";

const EditGoal = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    //Initialize variables
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { goalId, goalNameFromAddPage } = route.params;
    let selectedGoal = useSelector(state => state.userReducer.goals.find((goal) => goal.id === goalId));

    if (goalNameFromAddPage) {
        selectedGoal = useSelector(state => state.userReducer.goals.find((goal) => goal.goalName === goalNameFromAddPage));
    }
    //Deconstruct needed variables
    const { goalName, startDate, status, tasksArrayOfObjects } = selectedGoal;

    //Initialize States
    const [tasks, setTasks]= useState(tasksArrayOfObjects.fitler((task) => {
        if (!task.isComplete) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }));

    //Methods
    function deleteTaskHandler(goalName, taskId, taskIndex, updateAction) {
        const taskSnapShot = [...tasks];
        taskSnapShot.splice(taskIndex, 1);
        setTasks(taskSnapShot);
        //dispatch(udpateTask(goalName, taskId, updateAction));
    };
    /* Has issues */
    function completeTaskHandler(goalName, taskId, taskIndex, updateAction) {
        const taskSnapShot = tasks.slice();
        console.log(taskSnapShot);
        console.log(tasks);
        taskSnapShot[taskIndex].isComplete = "true";
        console.log(taskSnapShot);
        console.log(tasks);

        /*
        function copyArray(arr) {
            const arrCopy = arr.slice();
            const copy = arrCopy.splice(0, arrCopy.length);
            return copy;
        }
        console.log(tasks);
        const taskSnapShot = copyArray(tasks);
        taskSnapShot[taskIndex].isComplete = true;
        console.log(taskSnapShot);
        console.log(tasks);
        */

        //dispatch(udpateTask(goalName, taskId, updateAction));
    };
    
    navigation.setOptions({
        headerLeft: () => (
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomBackButton}>
                <Item 
                    title="BACK" 
                    iconName="md-close"
                    onPress={() => navigation.popToTop()}
                />
            </HeaderButtons>
        ),
    });
    
    return(
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <View style={styles.goalContainer}>
                    <SmallText>Goal:</SmallText>
                    <HeaderText>{goalName}</HeaderText>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.goalStatusContainer}>
                    <SmallText style={styles.headerTextMargin}>Started: {startDate}</SmallText>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                        <SmallText>Finished: </SmallText>
                        <SmallTextItalic>{status}</SmallTextItalic>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.pageDescription}>
                <DefaultText>
                    Here is where you can add, delete, or track the steps you need to do in
                    order to achieve your goal.
                </DefaultText>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.taskContainer}>
                {tasks.map((task, index) => {
                    return <Task 
                        title={task.taskName} 
                        key={"key"+index} 
                        deleteTask={deleteTaskHandler.bind(this, goalName, task.id, index, "delete")}
                        completeTask={completeTaskHandler.bind(this, goalName, task.id, index, "complete")}
                    />
                })}
                <View style={styles.touchableContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert()}>
                    <View style={{...styles.task, ...styles.addAStepContainer}}>
                        <View style={styles.addAStep}>
                            <Ionicons style={{ marginRight: 5 }} name="ios-add" size={23} color={Colors.grey} /> 
                            <DefaultText style={{ color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18 }}>Add a step</DefaultText>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
    },
    header: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        height: 80,
        //alignItems: 'center', 
    },
    pageDescription: {
        paddingVertical: 10,
    },
    goalContainer: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    goalStatusContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "flex-end",
    },
    headerTextMargin: {
        marginBottom: 4,
    },
    touchableContainer: {
        borderRadius: 10,
        overflow: "hidden",
    },
    taskContainer: {
        //borderWidth: 1,
    },
    addAStepContainer: {
        paddingVertical: 20,
    },
    addAStep: {
        flexDirection: "row",
    },
});

export default EditGoal;
```

Comment: Slice creates a shallow copy so making nested changes will also change the underlying state array object. Use something like map or reduce instead.

Comment: Ok so I copied it like so const copy = tasks.map(val => val) and the it still mutates the original state

Comment: I mean use map on `tasks` and create new objects with the updated values there. Just doing map like that will still cause the same issue. `const result = tasks.map(task => { return { ...task, whatever } });`

Comment: @Alexander Staroselsky yes this also solves the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit tricky. When you do:

```
const taskSnapShot = tasks.slice();
```

you create a new array, but inside that array, you won't duplicate the objects from `tasks` but just make a reference to these objects. So basically, `taskSnapShot` is an array of references. So when you modify an object inside `taskSnapShot`, you also modify it in `tasks`.

To solve this problem you have to duplicate the object that you want to modify:

```
const taskSnapShot = [...tasks];
taskSnapShot[taskIndex] = {...taskSnapShot[taskIndex], isComplete: true};
```